# Solving $x^5+px^2y^3+p^2y^5 = 0$ where $p$ is prime and $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you solve $x^5+px^2y^3+p^2y^5 = 0$ where $p$ is prime and $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$?

---

Working
 in modulo $p$  we have $x^5 = 0 \pmod{p}$ and $x = 0$ which is the only solution in modulo $p$ since $a^{p} \equiv a \mod{p}$ for any prime $p$ and integer $a$. Taking this back we get $p^2y^5 = 0$ which implies $y=0$. Hence the only solution is $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

---

**Edit/attempt 2:**

Since $x = 0 \mod{p}$ we can let $x = pm$ where $m<x$ then we get  $p^2 (m^5 p^3 + m^2 p y^3 + y^5) = 0 \implies m^5 p^3 + m^2 p y^3 + y^5$ since $p$ can't be zero. But now $y^5 = 0 \mod{p}$ ; suppose $y = pn$ where $n < y$. Then $p^3 (m^5 + m^2 n^3 p + n^5 p^2) =0$ and now $m^5 + m^2 n^3 p + n^5 p^2=0.$

Comment: The fact that $x\equiv 0\pmod p$ does not imply that $x=0$.

Comment: The second attempt looks better.  You might be able to get a proof by infinite descent out of it...letting $(x,y)$ be a minimal solution (smallest $|x|+|y|$ say), then your calculation produces a smaller one (a contradiction).

Comment: @lulu Since $f(x,y) = f(-x,-y)$. Can I say, suppose $(x,y)$ is the solution with smallest $x>0$ then $(m, n)$ where $m< x$ like a above - contradiction?

Comment: Trusting that your calculation is correct, then yes.

Comment: @lulu Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt looks good (the moment you note explicitly that $(m,n)$ is also a solution), and leads to a contradiction in very much the same way as the standard proof that $x^2-2y^2=0$ has no non-zero integer solution (leading to $\sqrt2$ being irrational).

Comment: Thanks. Since $(,)=(−,−)$. Can I say, suppose (,) is the solution with smallest $>0$ then $(,)$ is a solution where $<$ like above - contradiction? May I should relabel $(x,y)$ in that case but does that make sense?

Comment: @Nordstedt That looks like a neat way to finish the argument. Relabling might not be a bad idea; $(x,y)$ is a general solution, so giving the "smallest" solution a different name sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to emphasize the fact that the equation is a homogeneous polynomial in x,y, all "total" exponents are 5.  What that means is that, if we began with $\gcd(x,y) = g > 1,$ we are allowed to doivide both $x,y$ by the same $g,$ arriving at a coprime pair still giving a solution.

In contrast: if we began with $p s^3 = p^2 t^2,$ variables $s,t,$ we get equality with $s=p, t=p$ or with $s=p^3, t=p^4,$ but no solution with $s,t$ coprime. Generally $s = p^{1+2k}, t = p^{1+3k}$ as well as $s = a^2 p^{1+2k}, t = a^3 p^{1+3k}$

Answer (score -1):

Above equation shown below:

$x^5+px^2y^3+p^2y^5 = 0$  -------$(1)$

Equation $(1)$ has numerical solution given below:

$(x, y, p)=(-6, 3, -8)$

Comment: $p$ is a prime.